# Apply the Four-color theorem to maps combining two countries

Tags: geographics

The following code is an enhanced version of the code from 
["Find a Four-Coloring of a Map of Europe"](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/entity-based-geocomputation/find-a-four-coloring-of-a-map-of-europe.html).

```
provinces = 
  EntityList@
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {EntityProperty[
       "AdministrativeDivision", "ParentRegion"] -> 
      Entity["Country", "China"]}];
provinceneighbors = ({{"河北", {"辽宁", "内蒙古", "山西", "河南", "山东", "北京", 
       "天津"}}, {"山西", {"河北", "内蒙古", "陕西", "河南"}}, {"内蒙古", {"黑龙江", 
       "吉林", "辽宁", "河北", "山西", "陕西", "宁夏", "甘肃"}}, {"辽宁", {"吉林", 
       "内蒙古", "河北"}}, {"吉林", {"黑龙江", "内蒙古", "辽宁"}}, {"黑龙江", {"内蒙古", 
       "吉林"}}, {"陕西", {"山西", "内蒙古", "宁夏", "甘肃", "四川", "重庆", "湖北", 
       "河南"}}, {"宁夏", {"陕西", "内蒙古", "甘肃"}}, {"甘肃", {"内蒙古", "新疆", "青海",
        "四川", "山西", "宁夏"}}, {"青海", {"甘肃", "新疆", "西藏", 
       "四川"}}, {"新疆", {"甘肃", "青海", "西藏"}}, {"西藏", {"新疆", "青海", "四川", 
       "云南"}}, {"云南", {"西藏", "四川", "贵州", "广西"}}, {"重庆", {"陕西", "四川", 
       "贵州", "湖南", "湖北"}}, {"贵州", {"重庆", "四川", "云南", "广西", 
       "湖南"}}, {"广西", {"云南", "贵州", "湖南", "广东"}}, {"广东", {"福建", "江西", 
       "湖南", "广西"}}, {"湖南", {"湖北", "重庆", "贵州", "广西", "广东", 
       "江西"}}, {"江西", {"安徽", "湖北", "湖南", "广东", "福建", 
       "浙江"}}, {"福建", {"浙江", "江西", "广东"}}, {"湖北", {"河南", "陕西", "重庆", 
       "湖南", "江西", "安徽"}}, {"河南", {"河北", "山西", "陕西", "湖北", "安徽", "江苏",
        "山东"}}, {"安徽", {"河南", "湖北", "江西", "浙江", "江苏"}}, {"浙江", {"上海", 
       "江苏", "安徽", "江西", "福建"}}, {"上海", {"江苏", "浙江"}}, {"江苏", {"山东", 
       "安徽", "浙江", "上海"}}, {"山东", {"河北", "河南", "江苏"}}, {"天津", {"河北", 
       "北京"}}, {"北京", {"河北", "天津"}}} /. 
    Thread[{"安徽", "北京", "重庆", "福建", "甘肃", "广东", "广西", "贵州", "海南", 
       "河北", "河南", "湖北", "湖南", "吉林", "江苏", "江西", "辽宁", "宁夏", "青海", 
       "山东", "山西", "陕西", "上海", "四川", "天津", "西藏", "新疆", "云南", "浙江", 
       "黑龙江", "内蒙古"} -> provinces]);

colorcode = {{False, False} -> Red, {False, True} -> 
    Blue, {True, False} -> Green, {True, True} -> Yellow};
provincebooleans = # -> {x[#], y[#]} & /@ provinces;
eqs = And @@ (Flatten[
     Function[{province, neighbors}, 
       BooleanConvert[
          Xor[x[province], x[#]] || Xor[y[province], y[#]], "CNF"] & /@
         neighbors] @@@ provinceneighbors]);
solution = 
  First[FindInstance[eqs, Flatten[Last /@ provincebooleans], 
    Booleans]];
coloring = provincebooleans /. solution /. colorcode
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[
   Directive[Thin, 
    Black]], {GeoStyling[#2], Tooltip[Polygon[#1], #1[[2]]]} & @@@ 
   coloring}]
```

How can I join the administrative divisions of Taiwan to the list:

```
EntityList @ Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {EntityProperty[
    "AdministrativeDivision", "ParentRegion"] -> 
   Entity["Country", "China"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: "How can I add Taiwan to the list ...?" That's a question on which quite many people broke their head for more than 70 years... ;p

Comment: The original title and formulation of the question could have been interpreted as an attempt to make a political statement. I edited both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Definitions

The code from WRI’s ["Find a Four-Coloring of a Map of Europe"](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/entity-based-geocomputation/find-a-four-coloring-of-a-map-of-europe.html) can be modified/refactored to use `GeoNearest` and use the provinces of two given countries.

```
Clear[GetProvinceNeighbors]
Options[GetProvinceNeighbors] = {"RemoveEntitiesWithoutNeighbors" -> False};
GetProvinceNeighbors[c1 : Entity["Country", _], c2 : Entity["Country", _], opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{ads1, ads2, provinces},
   ads1 = 
    EntityList@
     Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {EntityProperty[
         "AdministrativeDivision", "ParentRegion"] -> c1}];
   ads2 = 
    EntityList@
     Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {EntityProperty[
         "AdministrativeDivision", "ParentRegion"] -> c2}];
   provinces = Join[ads1, ads2];
   If[TrueQ[
     OptionValue[GetProvinceNeighbors, 
      "RemoveEntitiesWithoutNeighbors"]],
    Select[
     Association[# -> DeleteCases[GeoNearest[provinces, #], #] & /@ 
       provinces], Length[#] > 0 &],
    Association[# -> DeleteCases[GeoNearest[provinces, #], #] & /@ 
      provinces]
    ]
  ];
```

```
Clear[MakeProvinceFourColorMap]
MakeProvinceFourColorMap[provinceneighbors_Association,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
  Block[{provinces,colorcode,provincebooleans,eqs,solution,coloring},
    provinces=Keys[provinceneighbors];
    colorcode={{False,False}\[Rule]Red,{False,True}\[Rule]Blue,{True,False}\[Rule]Green,{True,True}\[Rule]Yellow};
    provincebooleans=#\[Rule]{x[#],y[#]}&/@provinces;
    eqs=And@@(Flatten[Function[{province,neighbors},BooleanConvert[Xor[x[province],x[#]]||Xor[y[province],y[#]],"CNF"]&/@neighbors]@@@(List@@@Normal[provinceneighbors])]);solution=First[FindInstance[eqs,Flatten[Last/@provincebooleans],Booleans]];coloring=provincebooleans/.solution/.colorcode;GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thin,Black]],{GeoStyling[#2],Tooltip[Polygon[#1],#1[[2]]]}&@@@coloring},
    FilterRules[{opts},Options[GeoGraphics]],
    ImageSize\[Rule]Large]
  ];
```

### Countries with common land borders

```
aProvinceNeighbors=GetProvinceNeighbors[Entity["Country","China"],Entity["Country","India"]];
```

```
MakeProvinceFourColorMap[aProvinceNeighbors,ImageSize\[Rule]900]
```

[image]

### Countries with no common land borders

When the two countries do not share land borders the finding of province neighbors can be done programmatically, but in the case of China and Taiwan that is easily done manually.

```
aProvinceNeighbors=GetProvinceNeighbors[Entity["Country","China"],Entity["Country","Taiwan"]];
```

```
focusAdmins2 = {Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Taiwan", "Taiwan"}], Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Taichung", "Taiwan"}]};
focusAdmins1 = {Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Fujian", "China"}]};
aProvinceNeighbors=
  Join[
    aProvinceNeighbors,
    Association[#->Join[aProvinceNeighbors[#],focusAdmins1]&/@focusAdmins2],
    Association[#->Join[aProvinceNeighbors[#],focusAdmins2]&/@focusAdmins1]
  ];
```

```
MakeProvinceFourColorMap[aProvinceNeighbors,ImageSize\[Rule]900]
```

[image]

### Additional explanations

> Your map is missing Hainan Province. - Go with the wind

This is because the original version of `GetProvinceNeighbors`  (and now by an option specification) removes the entities for which `GeoNearest` produces no neighbors.

Since I made `GetProvinceNeighbors` to return an association of geo-neighbors those geo-neighbors can be adjusted as demonstrated in the previous section.

(Meaning, you can use your geo-neighbor associations to produce the maps you want.)

Here we see the difference:

```
In[103]:= aProvinceNeighborsNotAll = 
  GetProvinceNeighbors[Entity["Country", "China"], 
   Entity["Country", "Taiwan"], "RemoveEntitiesWithoutNeighbors" -> True];
aProvinceNeighborsNotAll // Length

Out[104]= 36

In[105]:= aProvinceNeighborsAll = 
  GetProvinceNeighbors[Entity["Country", "China"], 
   Entity["Country", "Taiwan"], "RemoveEntitiesWithoutNeighbors" -> False];
aProvinceNeighborsAll // Length

Out[106]= 38

In[108]:= Complement[aProvinceNeighborsAll, aProvinceNeighborsNotAll]

Out[108]= <|Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Hainan", "China"}] -> {}, 
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Fukien", "Taiwan"}] -> {}|>
```

Comment: Your map is missing Hainan Province.

Comment: @Gowiththewind "Your map is missing Hainan Province." -- With my update that province should be in. But if you followed and understood my original post, you should have figured out how to add it. Similar thing you did in your question -- you provided your own province neighbors associations.